# Converting non-printable bytes to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python3 `bytes` object (generated using a `struct.pack` or `to_bytes`) that I want to convert to a `str` object. Note that using `bytes.encode("ascii")` does not work here, because it will refuse converting non-printable characters.

How can I do that?

I'm trying to convert a integer to it's binary representation in an `str` object, so that `11` will be represented as `"\x00\x00\x00\x0b"` (note this is a `str` object and not `bytes`).

What I'm currently doing works well for lower integers that don't have bytes that are `0x80` or above:

```
In [94]: i = 11

In [95]: i.to_bytes(2, 'big')
Out[95]: b'\x00\x0b'

In [96]: i.to_bytes(2, 'big').decode('ascii')
Out[96]: '\x00\x0b'
```

However it breaks for integers that will be represented using the MSbit of a byte:

```
In [97]: i = 250

In [98]: i.to_bytes(2, 'big')
Out[98]: b'\x00\xfa'

In [99]: i.to_bytes(2, 'big').decode('ascii')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-d5fe6014b48a> in <module>
----> 1 i.to_bytes(2, 'big').decode('ascii')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I convert `i = 250` to `"\x00\xfa"`?

Thanks!

P.S.

The reason for this is that the function I want to call expects a `str` object and not a `bytes` object, I understand this is not the intended goal of pyton3 `str` objects (and appreciate the separation between `str` and `bytes`), however this is still what I wish to accomplish here.

Comment: "The reason for this is that the function I want to call expects a str object and not a bytes object" - what does that function do with the string you give it? How does it interpret the string?

Comment: The correct conversion (if any can be called correct) will depend on how the string is treated by the code that receives it.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks for your reply, I'm not sure why this matters (care to explain?) but that function will then encode the string in a specific way and send it as a packet. There is nothing that prevents / blocks non-printable characters from being used and manually specifying a string such as `"\xff\xff"` will work just fine.

Comment: You say the string will be encoded in a "specific way". What specific way? Do you want the result of the encoding to be anything in particular, such as `b'\x00\xfa'` for `250`? (Do you want the result of the encoding to have a specific length?)

Comment: I want to be able to provide the called function with `"\x00\xfa"` (Note this is a `str` object and not a `bytes` object), where the actual value is determined by an integer (instead of hardcoded). The function I call behaves well with such `str` values. The called function is quite out-of-scope of this quesiton. I could just as well want to print the `str` object, the important part here is a want a `str` object and not a `bytes` object.

Comment: While, obviously, this differs from similar questions due to the requirement to support non-printable characters (`\x80` and above)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
def int_to_str_bytes(i: int) -> str:
    return chr(i//256) + chr(i%256)

>>> to_str_bytes(250)  # "\x00ú"
```

Comment: Thanks! is is pretty close, though it returns `'\\x00\\xfa'` and I would like it to return `"\x00\xfa"` without the requirement to `print` it (I won't be printing it) and I need the data encoded as binary (and not a string representation of binary encoding).

Comment: @NirIzr I updated my answer, but it seems that `"\xfa"` is `"ú"`

Answer (score 1):

what about formatting the string representation (no decoding to characters!) of the bytes?

```
import struct

i = 250
s = str(struct.pack('>H', i)).replace('b', '').replace("'", "")

print(s)
>>> \x00\xfa
```